# What is the significance of orthogonality in wavelets design?

Tags: orthogonality, wavelets

I have come across a condition which states that wavelets must satisfy the condition of orthogonality but I am not sure what is the EXACT reason behind that? Is it to ensure that the scaled version of a wavelet function and it's translates do not overlap while representing the original function??

I am quite new in this area so please try to explain it in a simple way.

Thank You !!!

Comment: Are you familiar with orthogonality in more traditional settings (i.e. Fourier analysis)?

Comment: Well, I just have a rough idea about the fact that the integration of the dot product of two functions over a period of time has to be ZERO for the two functions to be orthogonal. I don't know how orthogonality impacts fourier analysis as well.

Comment: Orthogonality is a large concept in linear algebra generically.  Questions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399740/why-is-it-important-that-a-basis-be-orthonormal) get into it more.  Without a linear algebra background, it might not be easy to see why this is useful.  The short of it is that it makes computations much easier - If we have that $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are orthogonal, then $\langle a_1e_1+a_2e_2+a_3e_e, b_1e_1+b_2e_2+b_3e_3\rangle = a_1b_1|e_1|^2 + a_2b_2|e_2|^2+a_3b_3|e_3|^2$.  If the basis is also normal the computation becomes much easier.

Comment: Is orthonormality the same as orthogonality ? The reason I ask this is that there is another thread which discusses the importance of orthonormality in linear algebra. Perhaps, I can draw some ideas from that.

Comment: They're similar, but not the same.  Orthagonality says that if you have two basis vectors, their "dot product" (inner product) is 0 if they're not the same basis vector.  Orthonormality says that additionally if they are the same basis vector, their dot product is 1.