# Why is orthonormal basis better than linearly independent basis and orthogonal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, pattern-recognition

My course teacher for Pattern Recognition course made this statement that orthonormal basis is better as compared to orthogonal or linearly independent basis when it comes to pattern recognition, or linear algebra in general, but she didn't tell us why!

I know that orthonormal basis consists of unit vectors which are orthogonal to each other. But what makes them 'better'? Or in which scenario do the above mentioned other two basis fail and orthonormal basis survive?

Do orthonormal basis make analyzing things easier? How?
Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399740/why-is-it-important-that-a-basis-be-orthonormal), see the answers.

Comment: The questions look very similar but the context is different. I'm trying to get answer from machine learning perspective so that it'll help me in my pattern recognition course further.

Comment: I can appreciate that *pattern recognition* is important to what you are asking about, but most Readers on this site will not have a clear sense of what that means in the context of machine learning.  It might be better to exhibit a specific algorithm in machine learning which uses an orthonormal basis, and ask regarding that algorithm what would fail or suffer if a less structured basis (e.g. orthogonal basis) were substituted.  Look for previous Questions in [Cross Validated like this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092/bottom-to-top-explanation-of-the-mahalanobis-distance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you seek to express a vector $a$ as a linear combination of members of an orthonormal basis $e_1,e_2,e_3,\ldots$ It is as follows:
$$
(a\cdot e_1) e_1 + (a\cdot e_2) e_2 + (a\cdot e_3) e_3 + \cdots.
$$
Just try doing it with a basis that is not orthogonal. You'll see that it's far more complicated. And it's also somewhat more complicated with a basis that is orthogonal but not orthonormal.

Comment: Is the first term (a.e1)e2 or (a.e1)e1?

Answer (score 2):

If the coordinates of a vector $v$ with respect to an orthonormal basis are $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$, then$$\|v\|=\sqrt{{\alpha_1}^2+{\alpha_2}^2+\cdots+{\alpha_n}^n}.$$And if $\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_n$ are the coordinates of another vector, $w$, then$$\langle v,w\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k\beta_k.$$

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo. This shows that orthonormal basises can make calculations a lot easier!